# Re-create an Excel chart using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some charts in one sheet with already some data series in it. What I need to do, is to find a chart with a particular name and re-fill it with another series, where values are coming from VBA-calculated array, but Xvalues from worksheet's cells. 
While it finds the necessary chart perfectly, I receive very strange output on a chart, as if it is a combination of various series.Here is my code sample:

```
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To sh.ChartObjects.Count
            With sh.ChartObjects(i)
            If .Chart.HasTitle = True And .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Price" Then
                .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
                .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Price"
                .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = arr1()
                .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A" & nrow + 1 & ":A" & lastrow)
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End If
```

Could you please help me to determine what is wrong with that? Thanks!

Comment: At first glance a number of things could be wrong - is the correct sheet active?  You set `sh` to be the activesheet, but if that's the wrong sheet it all goes pear shaped from the start, you're deleting and adding a series - wouldn't it be better to just update the existing series so it retains all the properties of the series - colour, gaps, labels, etc, `arr1()` isn't defined anywhere, `Range("A" & nrow....` is looking at the currently active sheet - is that the correct sheet?, you're adding the title of "Price" even though that code will only run if the chart title is "Price".

Comment: You could just refer to the chart by name rather than looping through each chart and checking the title... `With sh.ChartObjects("MyChartName")`.  In XL2010 select the chart, click the layout ribbon and the chart name is in Properties.